# What's the best way to load content?

Tags: web, structure

Right now, the basic structure of my site is pretty bulky.

I know little about php, but I've managed to get by.

So, I was wondering - what's the best way to load content?

Right now, I have all of my pages saved with .php, using some include() and require().

I'm about to go through and update it using a php model, but I want to be sure I do it right.

So.. I'm going to be linking my keywords, description, other METAs into my database. Seems less hectic that way. Any words of wisdom before I go breaking into my massive site?

Right now:

- (doc tag/html/meta/etc)
- anchor.php *Loads css/js and other vitals
- /head
- header.php *Contains body tag
- [content (put inline on a static page)]
- footer.php *Contains

The new version is more like

- (doc tag)
- php writes everything from  to header.php
- Break for content and still use static pages???
- footer.php

Maybe it's easier to just have 30+ separate pages with a few lines in each than generate pages dynamically? I want the content to be easy to edit.

Thanks for the help! *(sorry if it's confusing at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in developing website, you must ever thinking about:

- maintain your code DRY (dont repeat yourself)
- encapsulate the ridondant code in some default structures (as programming oriented objects)

depending of the content that your site must show, the option (as you say) "30+ separate pages with few lines" is the best according to the 2 rules described above.

This let you the possibility to edit the website "speedly", e.g. if you want to edit the header, you must edit only one .php file and all the pages affects the edit. 
In other case, if you want to edit the content of the page "X" you can go directly to this page and edit the content.

Rememeber: try to have file that are bested implemented for the work that it must do, e.g. (something like that):

- head.php (all that are in the head tag)
- header.php (top of the page)
- menu.php (the menu)
- banner.php, banner1.php (something that are different between pages, but static itself as banners)
- sidebar.php (the sidebar)
- footer.php (bottom of the page)

Doing this, in 4-5 require/include you can build simply a new page.

Otherwise try to avoid pages that are re-used only one time.

Comment: That's essentially what I have. I even have 'segments' of content in .php files that are just html/css for ease of use. I guess what I'm getting to (in an unintentionally round-about way) is, is it worth it to put all of my content into a database and call it dynamically, or am I just causing more harm than good?

Comment: In the end I'd like to have a 'perfect' system that I know inside and out, and likely start setting up custom CMS for the sites I create.

Comment: All depending of the size of your site and how it develop in the future, if you have a 30+ growing web site the approach to put the content in the db and call it dinamically is the best.
As you say, if you are planning a perfect system and in second time a CMS, this solution is definetly the best. (in your CMS you can call the content that you want to edit on the fly, and so on change the website content)

Comment: So true. I guess it's just the next step. Time to get better acquainted with SQL. Thankfully, the hierarchy of the site is simple and clean :) Thanks for the input!